# Custom fields checkout checkbox toggle required?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2, knockoutjs, magento2.2.3

in the Magento 2 checkout I added 3 custom fields, a checkbox that shows the customer two password fields that are used to create an account.

[image]

Since the checkbox toggles if the fields are visible or hidden with JavaScript I want the password fields to be required when visible and not required when hidden.

How could I achieve something like this?

I'm creating the fields like this in `LayoutProcessor.php`

```
$jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['customer-email']['children']['additional-login-form-fields']['children']['create_account_checkbox'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'BB_Checkout/form/element/checkbox-overwrite'
        ],
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.create_account_checkbox',
        'description' => __('I would like to create an account'),
        'sortOrder' => '1004',
        'validation' => [
            'required-entry' => false,
        ]
    ];

    $jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['customer-email']['children']['additional-login-form-fields']['children']['create_account_password'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
            'customEntry' => null,
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'BB_Checkout/form/element/password-overwrite'
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.create_account_password',
        'label' =>  __('Password'),
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'validation' => [
            'validate-password' => true,
            'required-entry' => true
        ],
        'options' => [],
        'filterBy' => null,
        'customEntry' => null,
        'visible' => true,
        'sortOrder' => '1005'
    ];

    $jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['customer-email']['children']['additional-login-form-fields']['children']['create_account_password_confirm'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
            'customEntry' => null,
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'BB_Checkout/form/element/password-overwrite-confirm-password'
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.create_account_password_confirm',
        'label' => __('Confirm password'),
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'validation' => [
            'required-entry' => true
        ],
        'options' => [],
        'filterBy' => null,
        'customEntry' => null,
        'visible' => true,
        'sortOrder' => '1006'
    ];
```

And i'm currently hiding and showing them like this:

> create-account.js

```
require([
'jquery'
], function ($) {
return togglePasswordFields = function () {
    if($('input[name*="create_account_checkbox"]:checked').length && 
 $('.form-login .hidden-fields:visible').length != 1) {

 $('div[name*="create_account_password"]').css('display','block'); $('div[name*="create_account_password_confirm"]').css('display','block');

$('div[name*="create_account_password"]').setAttribute('aria-required', true);

$('div[name*="create_account_password_confirm"]').setAttribute('aria-required', true); 

$('div[name*="create_account_password"]').css('display','none');


$('div[name*="create_account_password_confirm"]').css('display','none');
        $('div[name*="create_account_password"]').setAttribute('aria-required', false);

 $('div[name*="create_account_password_confirm"]').setAttribute('aria-required', false);
    }
}
});
```

The aria-required, true/ doesn't do a thing right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up replacing 'required-entry' with a custom validator that checks if the checkbox is checked first.

> validation-mixin.js

```
 define([
'jquery',
'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/utils'
], function ($, utils) {
"use strict";

return function (validator) {
    var hiddenLoginFields = $('.form-login .hidden-fields');
    var createAcccountCheckbox = $('input[name*="create_account_checkbox"]');

 validator.addRule(
        'required-entry-if-create-account-checked',
        function (value) {
            if(hiddenLoginFields.is(':visible') || !$('input[name*="create_account_checkbox"]').is(":checked")) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return !utils.isEmpty(value);
                }
        },
        $.mage.__('This is a required field.')
    );
    validator.addRule(
        'validate-create_password',
        function (value) {
            if(hiddenLoginFields.is(':visible') || !$('input[name*="create_account_checkbox"]').is(":checked")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                var pass;

                if (value == null) {
                    return false;
                }

                pass = $.trim(value);

                if (!pass.length) {
                    return true;
                }

                return !(pass.length > 0 && pass.length < 6);
            }
        },
        $.mage.__('Please enter 6 or more characters. Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored.')
    );
    validator.addRule(
        'validate-confirm_password',
        function (value) {
            if(hiddenLoginFields.is(':visible') || !$('input[name*="create_account_checkbox"]').is(":checked")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return $('input[name*="create_account_password"]').val() === $('input[name*="create_account_password_confirm"]').val();
            }
        },
        $.mage.__('Please enter the same value again.')
    );
return validator;
}
 });
```