# Checkbox Toggle Required-entry

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, checkbox

I added a checkbox and i want to make the company required if that checkbox is checked, how can i do that? this is my js code

```
define([
   'ko',
   'uiComponent',
   'jquery'
], function (ko, Component, $) {
   "use strict";

   return Component.extend({
       initialize: function () {
           this._super();

           $(document).on("click", "#require-company-vat", function () {
             $('input[name="company"]').eq(0).closest('div.field').toggleClass('_required');

               if ($('input[name*="require-company-vat"]:checked')) {
                   $('input[name*="company"]').attr('aria-required', true);
               } else {
                   $('input[name*="company"]').removeAttr('aria-required');
               }

           });
           // component initialization logic
           return this;
       },
       defaults: {
           template: 'Chanz_CheckoutFields/require-company-vat'
       }

   });
});
```

**aria-required is not working even if its already true**

Comment: try using prop() in place of attr() like $('input[name*="company"]').prop('required',true);

Comment: aria-required is not working

Comment: @butching try this 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231397/custom-fields-checkout-checkbox-toggle-required/232391#232391

Comment: yeah i saw that already but same as in the comments, i need to view the complete plugin to understand that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a working sample.

> Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator': {
            'Namespace_Modulename/js/validator-mixin': true
        }
    }
}
};
```

> Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/js/validator-mixin.js

```
define([
'jquery',
'moment'
], function ($, moment) {
'use strict';

return function (validator) {

    validator.addRule(
        'required-entry-if-checked',
        function (value) {
            if (!$('#checkbox-id').is(":checked")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return !$.mage.isEmpty(value);
            }
        },
        $.mage.__('This is a required field.')
    );

    return validator;
};
});
```

> Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root" >
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                                                                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="required-entry-if-checked" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

reference [Add rule to rules.js Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209042/add-rule-to-rules-js-magento2/213630?stw=2#213630)